# Is it possible to make "coffee" with cacao?

Tags: food-safety, coffee, drinks, cocoa, science

I need to do a project for the uni, and my topic it's about cacao, and i need to create a new product with it, do you think it is possible or not?, please answer i need some help haha.

Comment: Er, no, that would be hot coco.  

Also, a big -1 asking us to do your homework.

Comment: Hint: there are like 8000 commercial products which unnecessarily incorporate cacao.  Do some googling.

Comment: Wendy, welcome! Please [edit] your post and add some details: What exactly are you planning to do and what is your question to us? And while it’s perfectly ok to ask for support, you might have noticed that some users don’t want to “do your homework for you”. I see you took the [tour] (well done!), browsing the [help] can give you a few additional pointers on how to ask good questions.  Don’t be disheartened because your first post was not so well received.

Comment: https://www.godivachocolates.co.uk/the-history-of-chocolate-mayans-aztecs.html cacao as we know it is an invention of VanHouten, a Dutch chemist. Before hot cacao hot chocolate was more similar to a greek or turkish coffee. ...

Comment: I've heard of it under the name "brewing chocolate" - chocolate nibs that are ground and brewed like coffee beans, flavored with milk/sugar afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean something like a filtered, water-based drink (to which milk and sugar may be added to taste), why don't you try it?

There are no food safety issues with taking cocoa powder (I find it in the baking section, not the hot drink section of the supermarket) and adding boiling water, nor with passing that mix through a coffee filter. You have my word as a random person on the Internet.

Test the result. You may want to experiment with proportions and soaking times, and it probably will want milk and sugar to taste like anything you recognise. Then you can read about the solubility of various important parts of chocolate in water. In particular look at what happens to fat in water. The melting point of cocoa fat may be of interest, and you may want to demonstrate the effect with a simpler model system.

Comment: I suspect cocoa would clog up a standard coffee filter?

Comment: @Stephie quite possibly. I'm sure there's a teachable point in that too. Certainly in comparing methods for encouraging flow in a clogged filter (strangely enough something I was doing in the lab yesterday's, abusing coffee filters  to strain the muck from a water cooling system)

Comment: Aztecs and perhaps the rest of the world did something like that before the process to get soluble cacao was invented in Holland https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dutch_process_chocolate